# integral $I=\int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am trying to calculate the following integral $$I=\int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}$$

> The answer in my textbook is $$-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\ln\bigl|\dfrac{\sqrt{2+x-x^2}+\sqrt2}{x}+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt2}\bigr|$$

Note that $-x^2+x+2=-(x+1)(x-2)=(2-x)(x+1),$ so the second Euler substitution is applicable. Let $$\sqrt{2+x-x^2}=t(x+1)$$ $$\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{2-x}=t(x+1)$$ $$\sqrt{2-x}=t\sqrt{x+1} $$ $$2-t^2=x(1+t^2)$$ $$ x=\dfrac{2-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ Now we need $$\sqrt{2+x-x^2}=\dfrac{3t}{1+t^2}$$ and $$dx=\dfrac{-6t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

So $$I=\int\dfrac{\frac{-6t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt}{\frac{2-t^2}{1+t^2}\cdot\frac{3t}{1+t^2}}=-2\int\dfrac{dt}{2-t^2}$$

Well, I don't see where my mistake is, but integrating the function $\dfrac{1}{(2-t^2)^2}$ won't be fun, even though it is rational.

So what am I missing, why does this problem become so technically diffucult, and what else should I try? Thanks!

Comment: And the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Have you tried to write $2+x-x^2 = 9/4-(x-1/2)^2$ and then put $3t/2=x-1/2$? Not sure if it works, however.

Comment: I also wonder why the downvote. I upvoted to compensate. Your mistake is when replacing $\sqrt{2+x-x^2}$ by $\frac{t(2-t^2)}{1+t^2}=tx$. It should be $t(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution you used is called Euler's third not second and i say mainly from personal preference it usually gives nasty rational functions

Using the actual Euler's second substitution

$$
\sqrt{2+x-x^2}=xt+\sqrt{2}\\ \ \\
x={1-2t\sqrt{2}\over1+t^2},\quad\sqrt{2+x-x^2}={-\sqrt{2}t^2+t+\sqrt{2}\over t^2+1}\\ \ \\
\mathrm dx={2\sqrt{2}t^2-2t-2\sqrt{2}\over(t^2+1)^2}\mathrm dt
$$

Now the integration becomes

$$
\begin{align}
I&=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}=\int{{2\sqrt{2}t^2-2t-2\sqrt{2}\over(t^2+1)^2}\mathrm dt\over\left({1-2t\sqrt{2}\over1+t^2}\right)\left({-\sqrt{2}t^2+t+\sqrt{2}\over t^2+1}\right)}\\
&=\int{-2\over1-2\sqrt{2}t}\mathrm dt={1\over\sqrt{2}}\ln|2t\sqrt{2}-1|+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Now that [you silently corrected your mistake](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4854902/2) (17 min after [I pointed it in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4854902/timeline#comment_10346632)), your "integrating the function $\dfrac{1}{(2-t^2)^2}$ won't be fun" becomes off topic and you could just go on:
$$\begin{align}I&=-2\int\dfrac{dt}{2-t^2}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{t-\sqrt2}{t+\sqrt2}\right|\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{t^2-2}{t^2+2\sqrt2t+2}\right|\\
&=-\frac1{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{2-x+2\sqrt2\sqrt{2+x-x^2}+2(x+1)}{2-x-2(x+1)}\right|\\
&=-\frac1{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\frac{x+4+2\sqrt2\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}x\right|,
\end{align}$$
which coincides (up to a harmless additive constant) to the answer in your textbook.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}$$
Let $x=1/t \implies dx=-dt/t^2$
Then $$I =\int \frac{-dt}{\sqrt{2t^2+t-1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{-dt}{\sqrt{t^2+t/2-1/2}}$$
$$\implies I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{-dt}{\sqrt{(t+1/4)^2-9/16}}$$
Now try yourself from here.